# Ubuntu - unable to extend partition with growpart - partition 1 could only be grown by 2046

Tags: ubuntu, disk-space-utilization, diskmanagement

I want to extend /dev/sdb1 partition

I extended disk for 2 GB in Hypervisor and new disk size is shown for /dev/sdb disk (from 20 to 22 GB)

```
Device     Boot    Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1  *        2048 40894463 40892416 19.5G 83 Linux
/dev/sdb2       40896510 41940991  1044482  510M  5 Extended
/dev/sdb5       40896512 41940991  1044480  510M 82 Linux swap / Solaris
```

But getting partition 1 could only be grown by 2046 [fudge=2048]

```
growpart -v /dev/sdb 1
update-partition set to true
resizing 1 on /dev/sdb using resize_sfdisk_dos
46137344 sectors of 512. total size=23622320128 bytes
## sfdisk --unit=S --dump /dev/sdb
label: dos
label-id: 0x000467a9
device: /dev/sdb
unit: sectors

/dev/sdb1 : start=        2048, size=    40892416, type=83, bootable
/dev/sdb2 : start=    40896510, size=     1044482, type=5
/dev/sdb5 : start=    40896512, size=     1044480, type=82
max_end=40896510 tot=46137344 pt_end=40894464 pt_start=2048 pt_size=40892416
NOCHANGE: partition 1 could only be grown by 2046 [fudge=2048]
```

Comment: Well, how do you expect it to grow when there are other partitions after it? You need to move them first.

Comment: Or just delete and recreate the other partitions ... it's just swap after all

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to remove/move `/dev/sdb2` and `/dev/sdb5`.

1. Use `sudo cfdisk /dev/sdb` to select partitions and delete/modify them.
2. Extend a partition in a partition table to fill available space: `sudo growpart /dev/sdb 1`.
3. Enlarge the mounted file system: `sudo resize2fs /dev/sdb1`.

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate further on the accepted answer, growpart only works in extending last partition in the disk, that is why it is mentioned in the answer to delete the 2nd/5th partition to make the 1st partition the last one in the disk and allow then the growpart to work.

> It only extends the last partition. It doesn't create or delete any existing partition.

[Source](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/5540131#:%7E:text=It%20only%20extends%20the%20last%20partition.%20It%20doesn%27t%20create%20or%20delete%20any%20existing%20partition.)